# How to save references to Firebase Auth Users in a Firestore document?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have an application where you can register and login. I did that using Firebase Auth.

And then I have a Firestore where I have multiple collections like "Requests" and "Offers". A Firebase-Authed user in my App can create new Requests, which I add like this:

```
    firestore
        .collection('requests')
        .add({
            category: 'Test',
            customer_id: this.props.appState.user.uid, // The uid from Firebase Auth
            link: this.state.productLink
        })
        .then(docRef => {
            console.log('Successfully saved!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

So as you can see, I'd like to store the users Firbase Auth uid to the request so I can query a request by a user later in my app.

The question is: Is that the correct way? At this point I don't want to create a users collection in my Firestore to hold more data for a user. In that case I could add a document with the uid as key and then in the "Requests" collection save a reference to the user. But in the current case I can't or at least I didn't find a way yet, reading the docs and searching google.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to create a users collection? Can you clarify what you mean by "But in the current case I can't or at least I didn't find a way yet, reading the docs and searching google." You can't figure out how to create a ref to the user? You could create userRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid)

Comment: At this point for me users collection doesn't really make sense because I don't have any further data to store for users. They don't have a "profile" or something. And with that quoted sentence I mean I don't know how I should store the "reference" to the Firebase-Auth-uid. I ask myself if the code I posted would be the correct way in this case as I only store the uid as a string to the field "customer_id".

Comment: As long as you only ever need to query based on the logged in user, i.e. currentUser, than it seems like a fine way to me! But, I'll let the experts chime in.

Comment: Hm, so you meean I can't query the users data from outside? Like for example if I want ro display all "Requests" and want to show which user sent it, I can't do a query for the users profile-picture or displayName for example? As these fields are stored in the Firebase Auth.

Comment: Based on the Firebase Auth docs, I don't believe so. If you want to retrieve information about each user, or store any additional info per user, you need to use a database.

Comment: Okay, yeah, seems like. The Firebase-Auth fields displayName and profile-pic-URL dont make sense for me then though.

Comment: You are able to search for a user on the auth() method of the admin sdk, but you'll need the uid to do so. In other words, you should consider storing a users table in any design that searches users other than the currently signed in user.

Answer (score 4):

Giving this an answer to avoid people having to read through the comments conversation.

The optimal route is to create a collection called `users` where the document ID is the `uid` of the user from `Authentication`. Easiest thing is to do this on new sign up, you can do this where you handle new user registration or you can look into Cloud Functions which would look for new authentications and run the function like this:

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // ...
});
```

Documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

With or without the users collection, storing the UID like in the sample works fine as long as you always have a way of retrieving the user's information. Creating the `users` collection makes manipulating the types of data you store for a user much much more flexible (because there's zero flexibility with the standard auth objects, for good reason).

Comment: But as @SVARTBERG asked above, he doesn't need any other field. He just have email and password.
I have same thing as requirement. I just want to show email of the user who created particular document.
Does this simplify? Open to hear more on this.